# Problem about conjugates of an element in a group.

Tags: group-theory

If $G = S_n$ is a non abelian finite group and $g$ be an element in it whose order is $k$. Then Is it true that all the elements of the form $g^i$, where gcd$(i, k) = 1$, are conjugates to $g$.

The thing which I know is that they have the same order. Prove or disprove?

Comment: This does not hold in general, so you should be looking for counter examples. In fact, it does not even always hold that $g$ is conjugate to its own inverse.

Comment: Let me edit the question

Comment: I have taken $G = S_n$ in particular.

Comment: Ok, do you know how to quickly check if two elements in $S_n$ are conjugate?

Comment: Same cyclic structure

Comment: Right, so is the cycle structure preserved when we take powers like this?

Comment: It depends on the order of the element.

Comment: For these powers i need to check.

Comment: If the element is a single cycle, will these powers still be a single cycle of the same length?

Comment: we need to find $x$ such that $ xg^ix^{-1}= g  \implies (xgx^{-1})^i= g $. Now  there is a nice form of writing a cycle of $xgx^{-1}$ in terms of cycleof $g$ and  taking it $i$ times just means we are shifting the cycles $i$ times. The gcd condition ensures that none of the cycles just vanishes. I think you can find it.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: Yes it is for one cycle.

Comment: Ok, then just expand to a product of multiple cycles.

Comment: Write the permutation as union of disjoint cycles. Then you are done.

Comment: So it means result is proved.

Comment: yup it is. Just write both the sides in terms of cycles and then  define $x$  to make it true.